# Intent shows false Activity, if a Bitmap is putted in

Tags: android, android-intent

I 've got 3 necessary Activities:

1. A Main Menue
2. A ListView of some News
3. A View of the details of one News

For the Background:

- All Data is loaded in an `AsyncTasy` to an List `List<classNews>`.
- classNews includes the Attribute title_picture_bitmap which is an `Bitmap`.

If i put the detail News to the 3. Activity without the Bitmap it works fine:

```
classNews thisNews = dataList.get(position); 
Intent intent = new Intent(NewsActivity.this, NewsDetailActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("title", thisNews.getTitle());
startActivity(intent);
```

but if i try to put the Bitmap in it, it jumps to Activity 1 (Main Menu) and not to Activity 3 (DetailView):

```
classNews thisNews = dataList.get(position); 
Intent intent = new Intent(NewsActivity.this, NewsDetailActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("title", thisNews.getTitle());
intent.putExtra("title_picture_bitmap", thisNews.getTitlePictureBitmap());
startActivity(intent);
```

Someone got an idea?

EDIT:

I extend my post to react of an deleted answer:

Eclipse treat it like the putExtra of an Bitmap like
`public Intent putExtra (String name, Parcelable value)` and i 've red that i could use it in the Detail Activity that way:

`Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("title_picture_bitmap");`

Comment: Does the logcat show anything relevant?

Comment: No, no Error or something necessary.

Comment: Can you show the code you're using for NewsDetailActivity?

Comment: Putting too much data (over 1MB, in particular) in an Intent is a recipe for having unresponsive activities and undefined behaviours. You should save the Bitmap to disk, and then pass the URI of the bitmap as a String to the second activity. Reading from disk takes negligible time.

Comment: This should work, but the limit must be much lower. I 've tried it with an jpg of the size 10k and it works, but the jpg that failed only got 50k. (I know that a jpg is more kompressed than the Bitmap representation.) ...

:( ... I thought i shoudn't save it disk.